# Reducing a string by detecting patterns

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Given a string, I would like to detect the repeating substrings, and then reduce **abab** to **(ab)<sup>2</sup>**.

For instance, **ababababacdecdecdeababab** would reduce to **(ab)<sup>4</sup>a(cde)<sup>3</sup>(ab)<sup>3</sup>**.
The string does not have the same character twice in a row. So, **aaab** is an invalid string.

Here is the Python that I wrote:

```
def superscript(n):
    return "".join(["⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"[ord(c)-ord('0')] for c in str(n)]) 


signature = 'hdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfb'
d = {}

processed = []
for k in range(2, len(signature)):
    i = 0
    j = i + k
    while j <= len(signature):
        repeat_count = 0
        while signature[i:i+k] == signature[j:j+k]:
            repeat_count += 1
            j += k
        if repeat_count > 0 and i not in processed:
            d[i] = [i+k, repeat_count + 1]
            for j in range(i, (i+k)*repeat_count + 1):
                processed.append(j)
            
            i = j
            j = i + k
        else:
            i += 1
            j = i + k
            
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
output = ''
for k,v in od.items():
    print(k, v)
    output += '(' + signature[k:v[0]] + ')' + superscript(v[1])
```

Which aims to detect the repeating substrings of length 2, 3, 4, and so on. I mark the start and the end of a repeating substring by using a `dict`. I also mark the index of the processed characters by keeping a **list** to avoid replacing **(ab)<sup>4</sup>** by **(abab)<sup>2</sup>** (since the latter one will overwrite the beginning index in the dict).

The example string I work with is **hdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfb** which should output **(hd)<sup>4</sup>(cg)<sup>4</sup>c(bf)<sup>4</sup>b(ae)<sup>4</sup>a(dh)<sup>4</sup>d(cg)<sup>4</sup>c(bf)<sup>4</sup>b(ae)<sup>4</sup>a(dh)<sup>4</sup>d(cg)<sup>4</sup>c(bf)<sup>4</sup>b(ae)<sup>4</sup>a(dh)<sup>4</sup>d(cg)<sup>4</sup>cbfb**.

However, I get this output:
**(hd)<sup>4</sup>(dcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdh)<sup>5</sup>(cg)<sup>4</sup>(ea)<sup>2</sup>(dh)<sup>4</sup>(hd)<sup>2</sup>(cg)<sup>4</sup>**

I don't know whether this is a well-known problem, but I couldn't find any resources. I don't mind the time complexity of the algorithm.
Where did I make a mistake?

The algorithm I try to describe looks like this:
First, find the repeating substrings of length 2, then 3, then 4, ..., up to the length of the input string.
Then, do the same operation until there is no repetition at all.

A step-by-step example looks like this:

```
abcabcefefefghabcdabcdefefefghabcabcefefefghabcdabcdefefefgh
abcabc(ef)²ghabcdabcd(ef)²ghabcabc(ef)²ghabcdabcd(ef)²gh
(abc)³(ef)²ghabcdabcd(ef)²gh(abc)³(ef)²ghabcdabcd(ef)²gh
(abc)³(ef)²gh(abcd)²(ef)²gh(abc)³(ef)²gh(abcd)²(ef)²gh
((abc)³(ef)²gh(abcd)²(ef)²gh)²
```

Comment: `ord(c)-ord('0')` can just be `int(c)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to match any repeating two chars and then pass a replacement function that formats the pattern you desire

```
import re

def superscript(n):
    return "".join(["⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"[ord(c)-ord('0')] for c in str(n)])

s = 'hdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdhdcgcgcgcgcbfb'

max_length = 5

result = re.sub(
    rf'(\w{{2,{max_length}}}?)(\1+)', # Omit the second number in the repetition to match any number of repeating chars (\w{2,}?)(\1+)
    lambda m: f'({m.group(1)}){superscript(len(m.group(0))//len(m.group(1)))}',
    s
)

print(result) # (hd)⁴(cg)⁴c(bf)⁴b(ae)⁴a(dh)⁴d(cg)⁴c(bf)⁴b(ae)⁴a(dh)⁴d(cg)⁴c(bf)⁴b(ae)⁴a(dh)⁴d(cg)⁴c(bf)⁴b(ae)⁴a(dh)⁴d(cg)⁴c(bf)⁴b(ae)⁴a(dh)⁴d(cg)⁴cbfb
```

Comment: Thanks! I always overlook the power of regular expression.

Comment: However, this does not give the correct result for the string abcdabcdabcdabcdabababab

Comment: @padawan made a slight improvement to the answer, the regex should now match repeating groups of 2-5 chars. Giving `(abcd)⁴(ab)⁴`

Comment: Is there a way to set the upper limit to length of the input string instead of a constant? The same problem also occurs when printing the repetition count. For a substring of length 5, it should be `m.group(0)//5` etc.

Comment: @padawan I was just updating with a fix for the length. You can omit the second number in the repetition match to match any length repetition, it may give unwanted results though in some cirmcumstances - `(\w{2,}?)(\1+)`

Comment: So, there is no way to write something like `'(\w{' + i + '}?)(\1+)'`? I ultimately want to reduce the input until there are absolutely no repetitions. For instance `(hd)⁴(cg)⁴(hd)⁴(cg)⁴` would reduce to `((hd)⁴(cg)⁴)²`

Comment: @padawan Sure, like this `rf'(\w{{2,{i}}}?)(\1+)'` for 2-i length repetitions or `rf'(\w{{{i}}})(\1+)'` for exactly i length repetitions

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code happens when you put together the list of repeating patterns. When you are merging patterns of length 2 and patterns of length 3, you are using patterns that are not compatible with each other.

- hdhdhdhd = (hd)<sup>4</sup> starts at index 0 and ends at index 7 (included).
- (dcgcgcgcgcbfbfbfbfbaeaeaeaeadhdhdhdh)<sup>5</sup>, which is a correct pattern in your string, starts at index 7 (included).

This means when you merge the two patterns, you get an incorrect end result because the letter at index 7 is shared.

This problem stems from the fact that one pattern is even in length, while the other is odd and their limits are not aligning. So, they don't even overwrite each other in `d` and you end up with your result.

I think you tried to solve this problem using the dictionary `d` with the starting index as key and with the `processed` list, but there is still a couple of problems.

1. `for j in range(i, (i+k)*repeat_count + 1):` should be `for l in range(i, j)`, otherwise you are skipping the last index of the pattern (`j`). Also, I changed the loop index to `l` because `j` was already used. This fixed the problem I described above.
2. Even with that fixed, there is still an issue. You check for patterns starting from length 2 (`for k in range(2, len(signature))`), so single letters not belonging to any pattern, like the `c` in (hd)<sup>4</sup>(cg)<sup>4</sup>**c**(bf)<sup>4</sup> will never make it in the dictionary and therefore you will still have overlapping patterns with different lengths at those positions.